# How to make ECharts text and legend area options responsive to different screen sizes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, echarts, graphing

In this case I'm using ECharts for react library to visualize data using a pie chart. When the screen size increases the graph text will remain as the same size. canvas size is changing but the other texts are not changing.

So, I want to make those text and legend area responsive when the screen size is increasing.

```
const optionPieChart = {
        color: [
            '#2B6AA9',
            '#2845AB',
            '#F8FAFF',
            '#4EBDDE'
        ],
        title: {
            text: 'Conversation Type',
            left: 'left',
            top: '10%',
            padding: 15,
            textStyle: {
                color: '#ffffff',
                opacity: '0.7',
                fontWeight: '400',
                fontFamily: 'poppins',
                fontSize: '18px'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            trigger: 'item'
        },
        legend: {
            itemGap: 10,
            show: true,
            padding: 15,
            orient: 'vertical',
            left: 'left',
            top: '50%',
            itemWidth: 15,
            textStyle: {
                color: '#C4D8FF',
                fontFamily: 'poppins',
                fontSize: '14px'
            }
        },
        series: [
            {
                // name: 'Access From',
                type: 'pie',
                radius: '80%',
                padding: '0',
                left: '160',
                data: [
                    { value: 1048, name: 'FAQs' },
                    { value: 735, name: 'Small Talks' },
                    { value: 580, name: 'Product inquiries' },
                    { value: 484, name: 'Escalate Hop' },
                ],
                label: {
                    show: false
                },
                emphasis: {
                    itemStyle: {
                        shadowBlur: 10,
                        shadowOffsetX: 0,
                        shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        backgroundColor: {
            type: 'radial',
            x: 0.3,
            y: 0.3,
            r: 0.8,
            colorStops: [
                {
                    offset: 0,
                    color: '#122C44'
                },
                {
                    offset: 1,
                    color: '#133351'
                }
            ]
        },
    };
```

I tried some media queries but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with window.onresize event

```
var chartEl = echarts.init(document.getElementById('someId'));
var option = {
  ... // chart options
};
chartEl.setOption(option);

window.onresize = function () {
  var width = document.getElementById('someId').offsetWidth;
  var fontSize = width / 80 + 'px';
  var legendWidth = width / 4 + 'px';
  
  chartEl.setOption({
    textStyle: {
      fontSize: fontSize
    }
  });
  
 chartEl.setOption({
    legend: {
      width: legendWidth
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Can I use this in react?

Comment: Offcourse :) React is JavaScript library